# How can I transfer my tokens on the Harmony blockchain?

Tags: node.js, web3js, harmony

I have my own token on the Harmony blockchain, I need to transfer some of the tokens from my Metamask to another Metamask wallet using node.js, but I have absolutely no idea how to do this.
I only know the contract address of my token.

I was able to put together a small code to transfer Harmony One to another Metamask wallet,
however, I need to transfer my own tokens located on the Harmony One blockchain:

```
const {Web3} = require('web3')
const { ChainID, ChainType } = require('@harmony-js/utils');
const { ContractFactory } = require('@harmony-js/contract');
const { Harmony } = require('@harmony-js/core');
const { fromBech32, toBech32 } = require('@harmony-js/crypto');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://api.harmony.one'));

const senderAddress = 'my metamask public token';
const receiverAddress = 'receiver metamask public token';
const senderPrivateKey = 'my metamask private token'; 

(async()=>{
  const hmy = new Harmony('https://api.harmony.one', {
    chainType: ChainType.Harmony,
    chainId: ChainID.HmyMainnet,
  });

  const senderAccount = hmy.wallet.addByPrivateKey(senderPrivateKey);

  const txn = hmy.transactions.newTx({
    from: senderAddress,
    to: receiverAddress,
    value: '1000000000000000000',
    gasLimit: '21000',
    gasPrice: '100000000000',
    shardID: 0,
    toShardID: 0,
    chainId: 1,
  });

  // Подписание транзакции
  const signedTxn = await hmy.wallet.signTransaction(txn);

  // Отправка транзакции
  const [sentTxn, txnHash] = await signedTxn.sendTransaction();

  console.log('Transaction Hash: ', txnHash);
})()
```